# Reading data from a TCPSocket in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, tcpsocket

This code sends the xml file to the server and waits to get the resulted xml file.

I am trying this on windows machine through bash.Complete rails environment is set over there.

```
require 'socket'

host = '13.74.255.195'
port = 10321
socket = TCPSocket.open(host, port)
  file = File.binread "/mnt/c/Windows/System32/workspace/preference/public/xml_files/20.xml"
  file.unpack('C*')
  socket.write file.bytes.to_a
  socket.write("\n")
  socket.write("ENDOFMESSAGE")
  socket.write("ENDOFMESSAGE")
  socket.flush
  socket.read
  socket.close
```

or (different way of reading data)

```
while message = socket.gets
  puts message.chomp
end
socket.close
```

or (different way of reading data)

```
def next_line_readable?(socket)
  readfds, writefds, exceptfds = select([socket], nil, nil, 0.1)
  p :r => readfds, :w => writefds, :e => exceptfds
  readfds 
end
while next_line_readable?(socket)
  puts socket.gets.chop
end
socket.close
```

Got stuck resultant xml file is not coming from the server from this ruby code.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: 1. You really should check that `write` actually writes all the data and that no errors occur. Note that `write` might produce a partial writing operation, requiring you to resend the remaining data .... this is often handled by creating a "user-land" buffer, polling the socket to test if data can be written, and sending any remaining data along with each poll event.

Comment: 2. Your Rails server is expecting an HTTP request, which should include HTTP headers before the XML data... where's the HTTP part of the protocol?

Comment: @Myst Can your share the example,so that I can get more clarity.

Comment: @namanverma - I'm sorry, I'm a bit busy to write an example. Search for HTTP protocol tutorials, since the Rails app runs an HTTP server. Then consider using POST to send the XML data. Maybe use [Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) instead of sockets... `uri = URI("http://#{host}:#{port}#{defined?(path) ? path : '/'}"); Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'file' => IO.binread(filename))` or something like that...